# What does send/recv/begin/end mean for AnyEvent's condvar?

Tags: perl

I'm at a loss what it means, though I'm read several examples on it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use AnyEvent;

my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar( cb => sub {
    warn "done";
});

for my $i (1..10) {
    $cv->begin;
    my $w; $w = AnyEvent->timer(after => $i, cb => sub {
    warn "finished timer $i";
    undef $w;
    $cv->end;
    });
}

$cv->recv;
```

Can anyone explain in more detail what `send/recv/begin/end` does?

**UPDATE**

```
my $i = 1;
my $s = sub {
    print $i;
};
my $i = 10;
$s->();  # 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code you provided, the condvar is there to prevent the program from exiting prematurely. Without the `recv`, the program would end before any timers would have a chance to fire. With the `recv`, all ten timers must fire before `recv` returns.

`recv` will block if `send` has never been called. It will unblock when `send` is called.

`begin` and `end` is an alternative to using `send`. When there has been as many `end` calls as there has been `begin` calls, a `send` occurs.

[AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent)

Comment: IMO the `undef $w` always undefines the last instance of `AnyEvent->timer`,what do you think?

Comment: @new_perl, no, just the one that just triggered.

Comment: Why ? IMO the callback is called **after** the loop,so only the last instance is referenced

Comment: @new_perl: Because `$w` has fallen out of scope everywhere else other than the coderef. Each time through the loop the coderef refers to its own distinct `$w` and each time the callback undefs its own reference. There is no scope whatsoever to `$w` after the loop aside from the reference to it in the callback.

Comment: @new_perl, Everything you run `my`, it creates another variable.

Comment: I know ,but the closure always refer to the last assigned value.I've updated my question with an example ,it outputs `10`,not `1`

Comment: @new_perl, What "last value"? Only one value is assigned to each $x.

Comment: @new_perl, Variables are captured (not values), so changes to variable are seen by sub that captures them. While you change `$i`, nothing changes any of the 10 `$x` except the `undef`. I fixed your snippet to be equivalent.

Comment: Why do you think there's 10 `$w` in the first place? IMO there's only 1 `$w`,which is assigned 10 different values..

Comment: @new_perl, Because everytime you run `my`, it creates another variable. (You said you new this!!!)

Comment: @new_perl, If there was only one `$x`, this would print 3,3,3, but it prints 1,2,3: `perl -E"@a = map { my $x = $_; sub { $x } } 1..3; say $_->() for @a;"`

Comment: @new_perl, If there was only one `$x`, you couldn't use local variables in recursive and re-entrant functions, and captures would be next-to-useless.